# Native cursor in Adobe AIR JavaScript with MouseCursorData

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, air

I've been reading this article: http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/03/native-cursors-in-air-2-6.html on how to create a native cursor in AIR without having to hack it by moving a sprite in place of a hidden cursor to fake it.

However I'm using HTML/JavaScript instead of ActionScript.

So far I have:

```
function nativeCursor(){

    // load in a bitmap
    var loader = new air.Loader();
    loader.load(new air.URLRequest('./assets/cursor.png'));

    var bitmaps = new air.Vector["<String>"]();

    var bmd = new air.BitmapData(32, 32, true, 0x00000000);

    var p = new window.runtime.flash.geom.Point(0, 0);
    var r = new window.runtime.flash.geom.Rectangle(32 , 0, 32, 32);

    var image = new window.runtime.flash.display.Bitmap(loader.content);

    bmd.copyPixels([image.bitmapData], r, p);

    bitmaps.push(bmd);

    var mcd = new window.runtime.flash.ui.MouseCursorData();

    mcd.data = bitmaps;
    mcd.hotSpot = new Point(0, 0);
    mcd.frameRate = 24;

    window.runtime.flash.ui.Mouse.registerCursor("defaultCursor", mcd);
    window.runtime.flash.ui.Mouse.cursor = "defaultCursor";

}
```

But I get an error `TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@2b9d1f1 to flash.display.BitmapData.` for this line: `bmd.copyPixels([image.bitmapData], r, p);`

If I remove the brackets for that line so it's just: `bmd.copyPixels(image.bitmapData, r, p);` the error becomes `TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter sourceBitmapData must be non-null.`

So I'm assuming that the error is because the bitmap data is null... but why? The image is being loaded in fine so is the way I'm trying to get the bitmap data incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### BitmapData, not String

The vector is supposed to be of type `BitmapData`, not `String`, that is:

```
air.Vector["<flash.display.BitmapData>"]
```

See **[HTML Developer’s Guide for Adobe AIR - Working with Vectors](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS144092a96ffef7cc49253a7c1264ea11ad3-8000.html)** for more information.

### Asynchronous loaders

Also the `Loader` class probably works asynchronously in JavaScript too, it's not documented properly in the HTML API reference and I've never used JS for AIR development, so I can only assume that, and that one can refer to the AS3 reference for the missing docs, however it makes sense judging from the available examples.

**[http://help.adobe.com/.../html/flash/display/BitmapData.html#includeExamplesSummary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/display/BitmapData.html#includeExamplesSummary)**

### Loader.bitmapData doesn't exist

There is no `bitmapData` property on the `Loader` class, only a `content` property that holds a `DisplayObject`, which might actually be a `Bitmap` object which in turn *has* a `bitmapData` property.

### An example

Here's some untested example code that should get you started:

```
var mcd = new window.runtime.flash.ui.MouseCursorData();
mcd.hotSpot = new air.Point(0, 0);
mcd.frameRate = 24;

var loader = new air.Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, function(event)
{       
    var image = air.Bitmap(loader.content);     

    var bitmaps = new air.Vector["<flash.display.BitmapData>"]();
    bitmaps.push(image.bitmapData);

    mcd.data = bitmaps;

    air.Mouse.registerCursor('defaultCursor', mcd);
    air.Mouse.cursor = 'defaultCursor';
});

var request = new air.URLRequest('./assets/cursor.png');
loader.load(request);
```

Comment: Cool thanks. However it throws the error: `TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.` but doesn't give any line numbers where the error happened.

Comment: @Cameron As I said, it's untested :) I can't test it right now, so you'll have to do some trial and error and remove bits of the code one by one to figure out what's causing the error, I'll update my answer later on.

Comment: Ah it's because you had two `new` where you declare the Vector class.

Comment: Here's the issue though... where would you call this code so that it sets this as the default cursor? As I originally ran it onload for the body but this only changes it when dragging the actual window chrome and not the default state for when moving the mouse around the AIR application. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Cameron I don't know, I remember that it works out of the box with Flash/AS3. Maybe there's a limitation for HTML apps, or it requires some additional coding (unlikely though since the docs don't say anything about it, but who knows), or maybe it's even a bug, I can't tell.

Comment: @Cameron I've just tested it, and the cursor also shows at the very border of the stage (there's like a 1 pixel gap where it's being activated). Not sure what's wrong here, I couldn't find _anything_ on the web regarding custom cursors in HTML AIR, seems like it's even more dead than FlasCC ;)

Comment: This fixes the issue: `setInterval(function(){ nativeCursor(); }, 1000);` so it's as though it needs applying AFTER something... I wonder what though?

Comment: @Cameron I tried something similar, but even changing the cursor waaaay later didn't do it. Btw, that looks like it may cause you trouble some day as it's an endless loop (or is that what makes it work actually, reapplying again and again?), you probably want to use `setTimeout()` instead, however, for me neither does work ;) What I've observed is that the cursor works for me when the window loses the focus due to an `alert()` triggered in the `NativeWindow.ACTIVATE` event, but only when caused by clicking the icon in the taskbar twice, it doesn't work when using the windows minimize button :P

Comment: I've been able to get it to work but it's an awful hack. In fact I've submitted a bug to Adobe and upload a ZIP with the code I've managed to get working... Feel free to have a play with the code: http://pastebin.com/jkULyXiG as you can see I use cleartimeouts to stop the cursors being re-applied when I want to change it.